# How will I know whether my phone supports wireless charging or not?

Tags: wireless-charging

I am planning to buy a wireless charger for my phone, and then planning to make one myself.
But I don't want to waste my parent's money to buy that unnecessarily if my phone doesn't support that feature.
How can I understand whether my phone supports wireless charging or not? means, whether it has that hardware or not?

Comment: Usually, the Phone's specifications on manufacturer's website and info on Gsmarena.com are sufficient to conclude the presence or absence of it.

Comment: Is there any app for checking that?

Comment: Seems the best way is to just sit it on a wireless charger.

Comment: If you can remove the battery, chances are that you do not... If your phone Back battery cover has an aerial on it, the aerial is for Wireless Charging... You can convert device's to have it with certain battery's that have the aerial built in, because you can convert the device that doesn't support it... You can not really get an accurate result from an application.. The software is no different than a device that doesn't support it, so it is not easy to detect....... However this application says it can..https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wikimediacom.wireless.charging.checker